# Alter a specific character of a variable?

Tags: autohotkey

Is it possible to target a specific character in a variable in AutoHotkey? In this case I'd like to uppercase/lowercase the first character in the variable.

```
::foo::
InputBox, foo, Foo, Enter foo:
/*
Capitalize first character of %foo% here.
Do whatever.
*/
return
```

Comment: You never accepted an Answer and were given multiple examples. Can you please do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, [StringUpper](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/StringLower.htm) will do:

```
stringUpper, foo, foo, T
```

`T` stands for:

> the string will be converted to title case. For example, "GONE with the WIND" would become "Gone With The Wind". "

Other than that, you can always determine substrings using either [StringTrimRight/Left](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/StringTrimLeft.htm) or [SubStr()](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Functions.htm), alter them and append them afterwards:

```
firstLetter     := subStr(foo, 1, 1)
stringUpper, firstLetter, firstLetter
remainingLetters := subStr(foo, 2, strLen(foo))
foo := firstLetter . remainingLetters
; or, equally:
; foo = %firstLetter%%remainingLetters%
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative one liner to @Blauhirn's solution:

```
MsgBox % foo := Format("{:U}",  SubStr(foo, 1,1)) . subStr(foo, 2, strLen(foo))
```

This can also be done in RegEx fairly simply.

::::::Edited::::::::::

Here's a full Example of it's use with the concatenate removed...

```
fu := "fu"
bar := "beyond all recognition!"
MsgBox % capitalize(fu) A_space capitalize(bar)
Return 

capitalize(x) {
return Format("{:U}",  SubStr(x, 1,1)) subStr(x, 2, strLen(x))
}
```

Regular Expression:

```
;This is the only example that accounts for Whitespace
var := "   regex is cool!"             
MsgBox % RegExReplace(var, "^(\s*)(.)", "$1$u2")
```

NumPut/DllCall:

```
var := "autohotkey is awesome!"
NumPut(Asc(DllCall("CharUpperA", Str,Chr(NumGet( var,0,"UChar")),Str)), var,0,"UChar")
MsgBox % var
```

Comment: I might be misunderstanding something here, but what's the use of building substrings just to concatenate them again directly afterwards?

Comment: I'm confused that you are confused? It's the exact same concept as what you posted in your example, just shortened without your explanatory assignments. Good catch on that concatenate, I just checked and it is not necessary for it to properly return Foo(although that is what is still happening when it's removed). I suppose I could have added some more clarification as you did, I just didn't think it was needed as your answer was more than thorough enough.